# Revolver movie title significance

Tags: title, revolver

I saw the movie *Revolver* recently and was wondering why the movie is named such. The movie is basically upon the *ego* of a person and has a lot of *chess* analogy included in it.

So my question is: Why is the movie named *Revolver* when there is no analogy to revolver shown in the film? Wasn't the title *Chess* a much better and justified alternative as the movie title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Guy Ritchie](http://www.moviesonline.ca/movienews_13426.html):

> I've always been surprised that no other movie has ever been called Revolver because it just sounds cool. So I like the name, but I also like the concept that, if you're in a game, it keeps revolving until you realize that you are in a game and then maybe you can start evolving.

Comment: Translation: "I wanted people to think they're going to see an action film instead of a confusing two-hour metaphor". :P